# Shiny error: 'file' must be a character string or connection

Tags: r, shiny

Question #1:
My ui.R code:

```
fileInput('file1', h5('Choose input file: (Use only tab delimited text files)'),
              accept=c('text', 'text-separated-values'))
```

and server.R code

```
inFile <- input$file1
dat<-read.table(inFile$datapath, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

when I launch shiny, I am getting, `Error: 'file' must be a character string or connection`. But after uploading the file, the error goes away. I'm wondering what could be the problem? I'd appreciate any pointers!

Question #2:
How to suppress error message in R console, when shiny is running?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be reading your file inside a reactive function. For example inside a renderTable.

You then need to add

```
if(is.null(input$file1))     return(NULL)
```

as the first thing in your reactive function.

The error is because you are trying to read a file with path NULL that is the value of input$file1 before a file is uploaded.

Update: shiny now has a function that deals more cleanly with this. You can instead add `req(input$file1)` at the start of your render function.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion solved the problem, thanks a lot

Comment: Is it possible to have this error return a message, like `No data has been uploaded.`?

Answer (score 1):

You then need to add

```
validate(
  need(input$file1 != "", "No data has been uploaded")
)
```

This link will be usefull for you
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html