# 'file' must be a character string or connection

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app that uploads a table, runs a function, and displays a graph and table. The uploading file works fine, but I am unable to run the function and output the graph and table (We shall only focus on the table for now). I am presented with the error:

```
Warning: Error in read.table: 'file' must be a character string or connection
```

I have run the function separately in R, and works fine with the desired output. I have tried different read functions, and different separators/delimiters, and read the function in the reactive renderPlot function (as described in a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647951/shiny-error-file-must-be-a-character-string-or-connection)). Below is a snippet of the code I've been working on:

ui.R:

```
fileInput("file1", 
                  "Load Input File", 
                  accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")
        )
```

server.R:

```
execute = observeEvent(input$runButton, {

    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
        inFile = input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) {
            print(NULL)
        }
        podr_fun_graphs(inFile$datapath)
    })

}
```

podr_graphs function:

```
podr_fun_graphs <- function(p) {

    df1 <- read.delim(p, sep = "\t")

    ... # From here there is some data cleaning and manipulation of df1

}
```

Code similar to this was working a few weeks ago, I made some small changes and it then broke. Would appreciate any help to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `if` statement. You have written `print(NULL)`. But it should be:

```
if (is.null(inFile)) {
     return(NULL)
   }
```

R will go on to execute `podr_fun_graphs(inFile$datapath)` if you don't specify `return`.

Comment: There was still a problem with reading with the file, but when using `df1 <- read.csv(p)` and return like you stated above it works, Thank you

Comment: I now have the same problem again but when I try and load demo data instead. The error in the shiny dashboard shows the following... 

`Error: 'file' must be a character string or connection`
And in the R console it shows:
`Warning: Error in read.table: 'file' must be a character string or connection`
The `return()` suppresses the error but does not run the entire function as its not able to read the data